# database connection string location

Tags: database, string, model-view-controller, web, connection

Sorry for being such a newb in advance. So I am putting together a php MVC website from scratch. I was just wondering where I should put the database connection string? I was thinking that I should put it in each model function that needs to access the database, but that seems very repetitive. I was wondering what the most efficient way as to where the data base connection string should go. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in `Web.config` file.

Eg.

```
   <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20130603030321.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20130603030321;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    />
```

The name of the connection string must match the name of the DbContext class.

More details [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string).

Comment: Isn't that only for using Visual C# in Visual studio? Looks like that notation. I am working from scratch making my own MVC. Should I make my own web.config file? Thanks for the response, much appreciate your help.